# app with sails.js no cache browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want my app is not saved in the browser cache. I have this policy, but how do I apply all my views?

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
sails.log.info("Applying disable cache policy");
res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
res.header('Expires', '-1');
res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');  
next();
```

Answer (score 3):

In `config/http.coffee`, add a "nocache" middleware. In coffeescript:

```
module.exports.http = middleware:
  order: [
    ...
    "nocache"
    "router"
    "www"
    "favicon"
    "404"
    "500"
  ]

  nocache: (req, res, next) ->
    if req.path.indexOf("/api") is 0
      res.header "Cache-Control", "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      res.header "Expires", "-1"
      res.header "Pragma", "no-cache"
    next()
```

In this case, it caches everything except calls under the `/api` path. You can simply remove the if and disable caching for everything.

Comment: This is the right solution, since Sails policies are for incoming requests only, and it has no control over the responses

Answer (score 1):

Policies can be added in config/policies.js

```
'*': 'noCachePolicy'
```

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies
However, the above approach requires that all your views have an action defined in your controllers. Otherwise policies do not work in this manner.

- OR -

They can be attached directly in routes
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html
However, this method requires you to write out all your routes.

- OR -

I think your best method if you want this attached to ALL routes,views it to create your own middleware and place it in there. That way you don't have to deal with the two issues above.
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware